# Insert data in sqlite from server

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, synchronization

I am trying to import some data from server to my android app. Server gets data from sql server and returns it throw a `HttpRequest`. I parse the data from `HttpResponse` and store it in sqlite database upon the `JSONObject` is parsed.

However the number of objects to be inserted is high and the operation may be canceled intentional(by pressing pause) or unintentional(internet problem). So I have below choices:

1- Ignore inserting into database after parsing `JSONObject` and wait for complete successful response from server: This solution is highly bad because if a problem occurs the user should start importing data again.

2- Make a feedback to server when I insert a row to database. So if I resume importing data just new records are imported from server: It is good but imposes extra network communication and also may affect performance.

3- Get one data packed file and try to parse it: So I am sure pausing the operation will not cause to  data lost. But I prefer another solution rather than working with file.

What is the best way to handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through this choice two weeks ago.

I found the better way to manage these data is to build a web service in the server (for example, in PHP; i was using a wordpress blog), send to the web service an offset and limit request and then download the data in JSON format.

In this way, if you have 100 rows to query, you can tell the web service to give you the first 10 results, then you can parse and store them, and then, you can go back with another query asking the results from the row 11 to the row 20, and so on.

In this way, the app will manage many sequential requests (and the related low-weight JSON answers), instead of an extremely big JSON file.

You can also manage all these operation in background or with AsyncTask so, in the meantime, the user can work on the foreground activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is so good and I think it will solve my problem. I'll mark it as answer after complete implementation. So we can see other's solutions too. Thanks again.

Comment: However we finally decided to transfer chunk XML files, Your suggestion is very good. Thanks!